# Prevent Bootstrap 4 Dropdown from closing onClick using React without jQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble to get things right with the Bootstrap Dropdown. I can't use react-strap and reactbootstrap is not supporting bs4 yet.

What I want is that a dropdown doesn't close if if select an element and only if I click outside of the dropdown menu. I don't want to use jQuery and would like to stick to react. I was thinking of removing `data-toggle="dropdown"` form the dropdown element, as this seems to be the one that adds the `show` class to the `dropdown-menu`. After that I would try to implement my own logic, so that it follows my rules.

But still, because I hope that there is an easier/better way, I wanted to asked if anyone has any experience with that?